# Formik - Update initial values after API call

Tags: reactjs, redux, axios, formik, dynamicform

I'm getting my inputs dynamically from an API call based on a change in select input, but when I try to add to the initial values of Formik, it always gives me an error ...

```
Warning: A component is changing an uncontrolled input of type text to be controlled.
```

And it doesn't help if I set `enableReinitialize={true}` to Formik.

However, if I generated the inputs from a local JSON or object, the error goes away.

What am I doing wrong here ...

https://codesandbox.io/s/test-dynamic-inputs-with-formik-xr9qg

The form submits fine though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If anyone is facing the same issue, I just found the solution ...

You have to set `value={field.value || ''}`  in the input inside the TextInput component or whatever type you're using in order to fix this issue.

Comment: Thanks for that! I've been looking for this answer for a while.

Answer (score 25):

Better use `enableReinitialize={true}`. This is official Formik API.
You can check [this issue](https://github.com/formium/formik/issues/1033)

Comment: This saved a lot of time

Answer (score 2):

I had a complex, dynamic form and also came across this issue. There are a few things that I'd recommend for anyone debugging this issue in the future:

1. Set value for your Field component--like Ruby does above.
2. Ensure that your Formik component has a uniquely identifying key.
3. Track and debug your initialValues and ensure that all fields are accounted for. You shouldn't have to set the field value like Ruby does--so long as your initialValues object accounts for all of the fields. However, my form dynamically changed Field components--and Ruby's solution is the only one that worked.

If your form is not dynamic--I think it might be best to check your initialValues object first before implementing Ruby's solution. Formik should be taking care of those values for you--which is why it's such an awesome tool.

Comment: I agree. If the form is not dynamic, there's no need for this at all.

Comment: After the form re-rendered, I was getting old input values that didn't match Formik's current state.  Your #2 bullet above saved me.  For those who have a similar issue, put a random key on your input to ensure React doesn't just re-use the old value.  This is especially valuable on dynamic form fields that are constantly being refreshed due to other inputs.

Answer (score 0):

i've checked with `enableReinitialize={true}`. But its not working as much as expected. so wrote a `useEffect` like

```
 useEffect(() => {
        formik.setFieldValue('query_string', active?.query);
    }, [active])
```

it's worked !